# Accidentally moved a single folder from root, now can't boot anymore

Tags: boot, grub2, filesystem, directory

**What happened:**

I used a program with a really bad GUI file picker and as I tried to traverse the file system, I accidentally hit the "back" button on the side of the mouse which seemingly acted like a regular left mouse click that caused me to move a folder high up in the file system into another folder. I either moved a folder from root into anoter subfolder of root (e.g. moved `/A` into `/B`) or a folder from a subfolder from root into a sub-sub-folder (e.g. moved `/A/B into /A/C)`. *I also recall that this mistake likely happened near or in the `/usr` folder.*

**Problem:**

Immediately after this mistake, all icons in Gnome were gone (although applications I had open seemed to work fine) and as I tried to open a shell to try to revert my mistake, it wouldn't open anymore (the click animation played, but no window opened). I restarted the system and after some wall of text that was too quick for me to read (it was the typical checklist-style wall of text) I was greeted with a white text on black background message reading:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p5: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, 897720/12004096 files, 21338613/51200000
```

I waited for some time but nothing really happened after that.

**What I tried so far (using Grub's recovery root shell):**

1. I compared my `/` folder with that mentioned on the official Ubuntu website: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/armhf/apcs02.html. My root folder is a superset of all folders mentioned on that website. Specifically, it contains:

   `bin, boot, cdrom, dev, etc, home, lib, lib32, lib64, libx32, lost+found, media, mnt, opt, proc, root, run, sbin, snap, srv, swapfile, sys, tmp, usr, var`

   My `/usr` folder contains: `bin, games, include, lib, lib32, lin64, libexec, libx32, local, sbin, src`
2. I tried to find out which folders where edited roughly at the same time the error happened. For that, I executed `ls -l` and unfortunately no folder seemed to have a time matching that of the mistake.
3. I read up [online](https://linuxstoney.com/recovering-journal-error-on-ubuntu-boot-up/), most people recommend to somehow (Grub Recovery mode or via Live-CD) open a root shell and then do: `fsck -f /`. Those posts try to also fix the `recovering journal` issue, but theirs was caused by e.g. a power outage causing files to be corrupted. *I refrained from trying that as I don't think the underlying file system is broken, I just moved a folder in the wrong spot.*

**Question:**

How shall I proceed? If I could find out which folder I had moved, I could easily revert my mistake

---

**Update 1:**

**System information:**

- **Distro:** Ubuntu 20.4.?. Unfortunately, running `lsb_release` in recovery mode gives a `ModuleNotFound` error, with the traceback ending in `apt_pkg.Error: E: Error reading the CPU table`, so I can't tell you which exact version.
- **Kernel:** 5.4.0-81-generic

I ran `fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p5` from a USB drive as suggested, that yielded the following output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p5
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/nvme0n1p5: 897720/12804096 files (0.4% non-contiguous), 21338886/51200000 blocks
```

Note the number of files and blocks checked is exactly the same as in the printout I get when just booting directly into Ubuntu

Comment: yes you can, but do the changes booting from a live pendrive...

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; however a GUI file-browser does not have permissions to do what you're asking for under Ubuntu, so what OS are you asking about?  A GUI browser should only have access to directories in $HOME which will not impact the system boot.

Comment: I wonder if `dpkg -C` (or `dpkg --audit`) might be helpful in identifying what was moved?

Comment: I don't see `/usr/share` in your list.

Comment: @guiverc Sorry I was not explicit on the system, I added the information. I agree with you that the application (MeshLab, a 3D viewer) doesn't have write access outside the `$HOME` directory and therefore isn't able to perform such modifications. Nevertheless, the problem appeared right when I used the file picker.

Comment: @steeldriver running either command in Grub's recovery root shell doesn't produce any output

Comment: @mook765 You just saved me! That indeed did the trick, my machine booted up like normal! Is there a principled way of discovering that to be the problem?

Comment: If everything works normal I'd tend to say we found the culprit...

Comment: Indeed, everything's back to normal!